# Indent command doesn't work on first paragraph

Tags: indentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I indent the paragraphs which follow a heading?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31555/how-can-i-indent-the-paragraphs-which-follow-a-heading)

hope you can help me with this. I am having trouble making the \indent command work on the first line of my text. Any ideas why it might not be working?

Comment: Do you mean the first line after a section heading? Try the `indentfirst` package

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31555/how-can-i-indent-the-paragraphs-which-follow-a-heading

Comment: @David: yes, indeed. Is that the problem?

Comment: OK we'll close this as a duplicate then, glad you got it working.