# Changing text below \section to be indented

Tags: sectioning, indentation, sections-paragraphs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How can I indent the paragraphs which follow a heading?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31555/how-can-i-indent-the-paragraphs-which-follow-a-heading)

I'm using the report class in LaTeX and when I use, say

```
\section{Foo}
This is a section about Foo.
```

I get (arrows indicate white space)

> 1.1 -> Foo
>
> This is a section about Foo.

When what I REALLY want (don't judge me, I just do) is:

> 1.1 -> Foo
>
> ----> This is a section about Foo.

(i.e. the text "This is a section about Foo" is vertically aligned with Foo, not with 1.1. I also want the rest of the paragraph indented across (not just the first line).) How do I do this?

Comment: Hi Hugh, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) How about putting the `1.1` in the margin? That seems like it would be easier, and would have a very similar visual result. If so, have a look at [theorem-name-numbering-in-margin](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59244/theorem-name-numbering-in-margin) and the links within

Comment: @Hugh Your question has been marked as a duplicate of another one, but there is also a second possible duplicate suggested by cmhughes. Could you let us know which is more useful for you (if indeed you do agree that this is a duplicate)? I can then make sure that the 'right' one is linked.