# Lyx: first chapter line indented

Tags: indentation, lyx, chapters

In Lyx, how can I make sure that the first line of each Chapter is indented? I'm writing a "report" document, if that matters.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31555/how-can-i-indent-the-paragraphs-which-follow-a-heading

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indentation on the first paragraph can be forced in this way.
Insert into `Document->Settings->LaTeX Preamble` this line:

```
 \usepackage{indentfirst}
```

However that appears in lyx

Comment: Yes, that's right. I don't know where or how to insert it with Lyx, though.

Comment: random google search for "usepackage lyx" turned up http://lyx.475766.n2.nabble.com/How-to-install-new-packages-to-Lyx-td3549182.html  which details the menu options for adding stuff to the preamble (last bit of the last answer)

Comment: @RickyRobinson Go to Document Settings > LaTeX Preamble. Also you might want to look at the useful Help files. Start from the top and work your way down. The first few are user-friendly and not too technical.