# Paragraph after \section doesn't indent

Tags: sectioning, indentation, paragraphs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I indent the paragraphs which follow a heading?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31555/how-can-i-indent-the-paragraphs-which-follow-a-heading)

I want to ask why "Hello!" doesn't indent.

```
% work1.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
   \section{Introduction}

   Hello!

   Hi

\end{document}
```

Comment: the section in article class is defined so, that the paragraph after it is not indented

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). The point of indenting a paragraph is to make it obvious that this is the start of a new paragraph. After a `\section` it is obvious that it is the start of a new paragraph so no indent is added.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's a common rule for indent in some languages: it's indent only the second and other paragraph.

If you want indent first paragraph too: `\usepackage{indentfirst}`.

Comment: Can I have a reference for this rule?

Comment: @ziyuang For example [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39232/9790).

Comment: You can also do \indent\indent.

Comment: @Doug, this double indent hack is perfect! any reason why this works? thanks~