# Parindent not working for subsection paragraph

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, sections-paragraphs

This is the code:

```
\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Background of the Project}
\setlength{\parindent}{10ex}
An Information System (IS) is a collection of integrated modules that collect, manipulate, and...
```

This is the output:

[image: Output]

The `\parindent` doesn't seem to be working. I need the paragraph to be indented.

I'd prefer a global solution, where all paragraphs are indented unless otherwise instructed.

Comment: `parindent` is likely already set to a useful value; you don't need to set it again. The first paragraph after a heading (like the subsection above) is not intended by default, because that is the standard typographic convention in the English world. You can use the package `indentfirst` to override this. See questions [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31555/), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79733), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196922/), [4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39227/no-indent-in-the-first-paragraph-in-a-section), etc.

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SE! Good luck with your typesetting. From your next question, please include a complete (but minimal) compilable example, starting with (if you're using LaTeX) `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**LaTeX** don't indent the first paragraph after of a title (*section* or *subsection*, etc). Use the package `indentfirst`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Background of the Project}
\setlength{\parindent}{10ex} % ???
An Information System (IS) is a collection of integrated modules that collect, manipulate, and...

Other paragraph ...
\end{document}
```