# first line of section/subsection has no indentation

Tags: spacing, indentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I indent the paragraphs which follow a heading?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31555/how-can-i-indent-the-paragraphs-which-follow-a-heading)

```
            \tableofcontents
        \pagestyle{empty}

        \newpage

        \section{intro}
        \setcounter{page}{1}
        \subsection{sub}
   First text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    \\
   Second text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
        \subsection{sub}
        \subsection{sub}
```

Basically that's my code and what happens when I generate the pdf is that where it says "first" no indendation appears, despite me trying to use `\indent`. However, where it says "second" the indentation works. I've tried `\paragraph` and it doesn't help.

Comment: same topic as [How can I indent the paragraphs which follow a heading?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31555/).