# The indent setting is not consistent

Tags: indentation

The paragraphs in Chpaters and Sections have indent. But the first paragraph of the subsection does not have indent.

In the .cls file, it is set as

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

And what should I do if I don't want indent in all paragraphs?

Please check the attached figure. Many thanks!

[image: Figure]

Comment: please show an example that demonstrates the problem. The output you show is not generated with  `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` if you have set that some code you have not shown has set it back. probably you can add `\usepackage{indentfirst}`  to indent the first paragraph after a section head

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The figure shown in the question demonstrates that there is no indent only in the first paragraph of the subsection. In addition, I am not familiar with the .cls, as it is from a template. There are some relevant codes: \setlength{\parskip}{2ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex};\setlength{\parindent}{0pt};\setlength{\footskip}{26pt};

Comment: as I said above the image you show is from a document with non zero parskip so the code fragments you show are not being used. make a small complete example document and post the output generated by the code you post

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question.  You do not identify the document class, and that's where the indents are set.  Since different classes define that differently, only by looking at the definitions in the used class will it be possible to do anything but guess.  And that doesn't help anybody.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I indent the paragraphs which follow a heading?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31555/how-can-i-indent-the-paragraphs-which-follow-a-heading)

Comment: See also: [No indent in the first paragraph in a section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39227/277964)