# Why xelatex indents only the first paragraph?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\parindent 3ex
Some text, indented properly.
\section{Some section}
  Another text, without indent this time.
\end{document}
```

It works, but only on the first paragraph. All other paragraphs (they are located in sections and subsections) are not indented at all.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: A minimal example is needed. There is *no* `\beginclass` command and `\indent 3ex` will indent a line but also print "3ex".

Comment: This explains it. The first paragraph of a section is never indented!

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2631/why-do-i-need-to-use-paragraph-after-a-section-to-get-correct-indenting-wh/2632#2632 (duplicate?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing strange. By default, LaTeX doesn't indent the first paragraph following a section title.

You can countermand this decision by loading the package `indentfirst`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Some text, indented properly.

\section{Some section}
Another text, this is indented.

And also this one.

\end{document}
```

Notice that `xltxtra` should generally not be loaded. The right package to load is `fontspec`.

Comment: I don't know what is included in xltxtra, but at the very least changing it to fontspec breaks compilation immediately.

Comment: @Rogach What TeX distribution do you have?

Comment: texlive-full, installed it from repositories.

Comment: @Rogach On a Ubuntu system? Unfortunately it's really outdated, particularly for XeTeX and LuaTeX support. Installing TeX Live 2011 is not very difficult: http://tug.org/texlive

Answer (score 2):

I don't know `\indent`, but I believe

```
\parindent 3ex
```

is what you're looking for.

Comment: Same problem - it indents only the first paragraph

Comment: You should give a larger example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: added a minimal example to question.

Comment: @rogach have you seen a non-indented paragraph anywhere _other_ than immediately following a sectioning command?  indentation is suppressed in that situation, for good typogrqaphical reasons.